# ResponseError: operation not permitted

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, redis

```
import config

from flask import Flask
from flask_redis import Redis
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix

app = Flask(__name__)
redis_store = Redis(app)
app.debug = config.DEBUG
app.redis_url = config.REDIS_URL

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return redis_store.ping()

app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

config.py

```
DEBUG = True
REDIS_URL = "redis://:123@localhost:6379/0"
```

/etc/redis/redis.conf

```
...
requirepass 123
```

ERROR:

```
raise response
ResponseError: operation not permitted
```

Seems like the AUTH command is not executed, or something similar. Any idea about the possible problem?

Comment: Can you connect with redis-cli and run `MONITOR` to see what is reaching the server?

Comment: @soveran The command works, but can't detect any action from flask to redis when I reload the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to its README, Flask-Redis looks for a key called `REDIS_URL` as part of the Flask config.

> ### Configuration
>
> Your configuration should be declared within your Flask config. You can declare
>   via a Redis URL containing the database
>
> ```
> REDIS_URL = "redis://:password@localhost:6379/0"
> ```

Without setting that `redis_store` will just use the default settings, which won't include your password.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['REDIS_URL'] = config.REDIS_URL
redis_store = Redis(app)
```

Comment: This code does not even run. TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable, at least for me.

Comment: On which line do you get the `TypeError`?

Comment: I suspect that `redis_store.ping` returns a `bool`, which is not a valid response object.